# Add Error Handling in Generic HTTPClient class

Tags: c#, xamarin, exception, httpclient

I have a generic class for using performing CRUD operation in network.

```
 public class RequestService:IRequest
{
    public HttpClient GetClient()
    {
         string USERNAME = "XXXXXX";
         string PASSWORD = "XXXXX";
         string BASE_ADDRESS = "https://something.net/api/sync/";

        var authValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}")));
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_ADDRESS),
            DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = authValue }
        };
        return client;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(jsonString);
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), url);
        var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequest).Result;
        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return jsonString;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TRequest, TResult>(HttpClient client, TRequest t,string url)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(jsonString);
        return result;

    }
}
```

And i have a custom class from where the network services gets called.

```
 public class DeviceService:IDevice
{
    private IRequest RequestService;

    public DeviceService(IRequest request)
    {
        RequestService = request;
    }

    public async Task<int> GetDeviceID()
    {
        var client = RequestService.GetClient();
        var id = await RequestService.PostAsync<Object, int>(client, null, "Registerdevice");
        return id;
    }
}
```

And In ViewModel:

```
DeviceService.GetDeviceID();
```

So everything works fine when i have stable internet or success response from the server. Now i want to add Error handling capability into the code including: no internet connection, other network exception and api error handling so that i could inform users about the errors. I am not sure how to do it. I have tried using try-catch block inside 'RequestService' class and read each of different exception and throw it, then it would mean i have to add try-catch block in DeviceService class and ViewModel as well.Or Do i have to? I am not sure.

Comment: Use try...catch..in all the methods of `RequestService` class. Handle exception in catch block, log the error, rethrow the exception if you want to handle it at top layer or return default value of `TResult` if you don't want the exception to be propagated.

Comment: @MichaelRandall sorry for usage of such informal term but I would appreciate any input in this issue.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so you mean i need to use try..catch in DeviceService class and catch the thrown exception from RequestService class and again throw error to ViewModel?

Comment: Yes... correct...

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it? Without try...catch

Comment: When exception occurs in RequestService, you can throw some CustomException. And have try catch block in Controller to catch that CustomException and display proper in the View. There is no other way than `try... catch`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I used a try..catch in PostAsync method in RequestService. try{..... }catch(Exception e){ throw e;} This is catching the exception while try..catch block in controller is not working.Exception thrown from method in RequestService class is not getting caught.

Comment: Can  you update the original question with the code with `try...catch` and controller code ?